# How to post JSON to PHP with curl

Tags: php, rest, post

I may be way off base, but I've been trying all afternoon to run [the curl post command](http://www.recessframework.org/page/restful-php-framework) in this recess PHP framework tutorial.  What I don't understand is how is PHP supposed to interpret my POST, it always comes up as an empty array.

```
curl -i -X POST -d '{"screencast":{"subject":"tools"}}'  \
      http://localhost:3570/index.php/trainingServer/screencast.json
```

(The slash in there is just to make me not look like an idiot, but I executed this from windows using PHP 5.2, also tried on a Linux server, same version with Linux curl)

There must be something I'm missing because it seems pretty straightforward, the post just isn't be interpreted right, if it was, everything would work great.

This is what I get back:

```
HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict
Date: Fri, 01 May 2009 22:03:00 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.8 (Win32) PHP/5.2.6
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.6
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

{"screencast":{"id":null,"subject":null,"body":null,
         "dataUrl":null,"dataMedium":null,"createdOn":null,"author":null}}
```

Comment: Could you please copy-paste your .php file as well? Are you sure that the URL http://localhost:3570/index.php/trainingServer/screencast.json
runs your script? It doesn't look like a PHP URL.

Comment: @pts; Peter is using an MVC framework of some kind, take a look at index.php in that URL.

Comment: @pts I'm using Delphi for PHP (hence the :3570) and the Recess MVC framework w/out .htaccess file, hence the index.php/ in the url.

Comment: Don’t forget to send it as `application/json`.

Comment: You need to escape your quotation marks, dude.

Comment: Its not necessary to escape the double quotes when embedding them in simple ones.

Comment: What does the -i flag do?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Jordans analysis of why the $_POST-array isn't populated is correct. However, you can use

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

to just retrieve the http body and handle it yourself. See [PHP input/output streams](https://www.php.net/wrappers.php).

From a protocol perspective this is actually more correct, since you're not really processing http multipart form data anyway. Also, use application/json as content-type when posting your request.

Comment: Doing json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true) worked. Thanks

Comment: FANTASTIC. I was having a lot of trouble with Zend thinking it was stripping the post.. A simple extraction which worked for me. Also Peter Turners addition of json_decode() providing a \stdClass object. I used it for Garmin API ping responses

Answer (score 120):

Normally the parameter `-d` is interpreted as form-encoded.  You need the `-H` parameter:

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"screencast":{"subject":"tools"}}' \
http://localhost:3570/index.php/trainingServer/screencast.json
```

Answer (score 19):

I believe you are getting an empty array because PHP is expecting the posted data to be in a Querystring format (key=value&key1=value1).

Try changing your curl request to:

```
curl -i -X POST -d 'json={"screencast":{"subject":"tools"}}'  \
      http://localhost:3570/index.php/trainingServer/screencast.json
```

and see if that helps any.

Comment: Yes, the `-H "Content-Type: application/json"` did not work for me.

Answer (score 14):

You need to set a few extra flags so that curl sends the data as JSON.

#### command

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
       -X POST \
       -d '{"JSON": "HERE"}' \
       http://localhost:3000/api/url
```

#### flags

- `-H`: custom header, next argument is expected to be header
- `-X`: custom HTTP verb, next argument is expected to be verb
- `-d`: sends the next argument as data in an HTTP POST request

#### resources

- [cURL manpage](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)
- [cURL examples](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should escape the quotes like this:

```
curl -i -X POST -d '{\"screencast\":{\"subject\":\"tools\"}}'  \
  http://localhost:3570/index.php/trainingServer/screencast.json
```

Comment: On Windows this actually worked for me, but using double quotes to enclose the whole json string.

Comment: on windows you have to escape double quotes as Josef suggested above. He is right.