# file_get_contents("php://input") or $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, which one is better to get the body of JSON request?

Tags: php, json, xmlhttprequest

`file_get_contents("php://input")` or `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` - which one is better to get the body of JSON request?

And which request type (`GET` or `POST`) should I use to send JSON data when using client side `XmlHTTPRequest`?

My question was inspired from this answer:
[How to post JSON to PHP with curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813487/how-to-post-json-to-php-with-curl/813512#813512)

Quote from that answer:

> From a protocol perspective `file_get_contents("php://input")` is actually more correct, since you're not really processing http multipart form data anyway.

Answer (score 226, accepted):

Actually `php://input` allows you to read raw request body.

**It is a less memory intensive alternative to $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA and does not need any special php.ini directives**.
From [Reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input)

> `php://input` is not available with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Comment: In addition, as of PHP 5.6, `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` is considered deprecated, and `php://input` can be reused.

Comment: Also see [`enable_post_data_reading`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12777947/632951).

Comment: json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true) does this support in PHP 7.1 to get $_GET values from URL?

Comment: $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA has been deprecated as of PHP 7

Answer (score 20):

> php://input is a **read-only** stream that allows you to read raw data
>   from the request body. In the case of POST requests, it is preferable
>   to use php://input instead of $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA as **it does not
>   depend on special php.ini directives**. Moreover, for those cases
>   where $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is not populated by default, it is a
>   potentially less memory intensive alternative to activating
>   always_populate_raw_post_data.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php.

Comment: In addition, as of PHP 5.6, `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` is considered deprecated, and `php://input` can be reused.

Answer (score 17):

**file_get_contents(php://input) - gets the raw POST data and you need to use this when you write APIs and need XML/JSON/... input that cannot be decoded to $_POST by PHP**
some example :

send by post JSON string

```
<input type="button" value= "click" onclick="fn()">
<script>
 function fn(){


    var js_obj = {plugin: 'jquery-json', version: 2.3};

    var encoded = JSON.stringify( js_obj );

var data= encoded


    $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '1.php',
  data: data,
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }

});

    }
</script>
```

**1.php**

```
//print_r($_POST); //empty!!! don't work ... 
var_dump( file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Answer (score 4):

For JSON data, it's much easier to POST it as "application/json" content-type. If you use GET, you have to URL-encode the JSON in a parameter and it's kind of messy. Also, there is no size limit when you do POST. GET's size if very limited (4K at most).

Comment: There often is a size limit for POST, but it's usually set pretty high.  Check your `php.ini`.

Answer (score 3):

The usual rules should apply for how you send the request. If the request is to retrieve information (e.g. a partial search 'hint' result, or a new page to be displayed, etc...) you can use GET. If the data being sent is part of a request to change something (update a database, delete a record, etc..) then use POST.

Server-side, there's no reason to use the raw input, unless you want to grab the entire post/get data block in a single go. You can retrieve the specific information you want via the _GET/_POST arrays as usual. AJAX libraries such as MooTools/jQuery will handle the hard part of doing the actual AJAX calls and encoding form data into appropriate formats for you.

Comment: That's the point: i want to grab the entire post/get data block in a single go, because JSON is a  variable-less format, it rapresent just the data.

Comment: @Kucebe I don't see why this is necessary, why not put the JSON data into a POST field and be done with it?

Comment: If you want the entire JSON block, then why not assign the JSON text block to a form field and submit it like that? `<input type="hidden" name="data" value="json data here" />` is entirely acceptable and lets you retrieve it trivially server-side with $_REQUEST['data'].

Comment: Embedding JSON in a POST field defeats the purpose of the HTTP content-type tag, and is not as nice for debugging in Fiddler and browser debuggers (which can understand JSON). Also, many 3rd party JavaScript libraries POST JSON payloads as application/json.

Answer (score 2):

Your second question is easy, GET has a size limitation of 1-2 kilobytes on both the server and browser side, so any kind of larger amounts of data you'd have to send through POST.