# Save image from Flash, send it to PHP and return a URL string to Flash

Tags: php, flash

I use this code to convert an image to a BitmapData and store a JPG in a ByteArray.

```
import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder;

var jpgSource:BitmapData = new BitmapData (img_mc.width, img_mc.height);
jpgSource.draw(img_mc);

var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(85);
var jpgStream:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(jpgSource);

// here we need some code to send the bytearray but I lack enough knowledge to do it by myself
```

Now, I want to do the following:
1. send the ByteArray to PHP;
2. PHP must store a physical image_id.jpg on server;
3. then PHP must return the URL of the image to Flash;

Is this possible? How?

The first lines of PHP could be:

```
if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]))
{
    // get bytearray
    $jpg = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];

    // but I don't know how to save the image on disk and how to return the URL of the //image
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

the as3 part:

```
import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequestHeader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
```

var jpgSource:BitmapData = new BitmapData(img_mc.width,img_mc.height);
jpgSource.draw(img_mc);
var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(85);
var jpgStream:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(jpgSource);

//set the request's header,method and data
var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type","application/octet-stream");
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
//sends jpg bytes to saveJPG.php script
var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("saveJPG.php");
myRequest.requestHeaders.push(header);
myRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
myRequest.data = jpgStream;
loader.load(myRequest);
//fire complete event;
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,saved);
function saved(e:Event)
{
    //trace the image file name
    trace(loader.data);
}

the php (saveJPG.php) part:

```
if ( isset ( $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"] )) {
```

```
//the image file name   
$fileName = 'img.jpg';

// get the binary stream
$im = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];

//write it
$fp = fopen($fileName, 'wb');
fwrite($fp, $im);
fclose($fp);

//echo the fileName;
echo $fileName;
```

}  else echo 'result=An error occured.';

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731297/file-get-contentsphp-input-or-http-raw-post-data-which-one-is-better-to for the preferred way (using the php://input wrapper) instead of HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA.

Comment: Wouldn´t it be better to send the request in a binary format like this?

`loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;`