# How to properly retrieve a JSON string with PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send a JSON to my PHP script and for some reason is returning `null` in the alert message.

I've searched throughout Stack Overflow and other forums and used other people's examples but somehow I keep getting it wrong. I checked in Firebug and the request is being sent. I am very new to handling JSON queries.

Could anyone point at what I am doing wrong so that I can learn for the next time?

My JQuery Code:

```
  var name = $('#formName').val();
  var regno = $('#formRegNo').val();
  var charityinfo = $('#formCharityInfo').val();
  var searchimprove = $('#formSearchImprove').val();
  var finantialaid = $('#formFinantialAid').val();
  var contactname = $('#formContactName').val();
  var contactphonenumber = $('#formContactPhoneNumber').val();
  var contactfaxnumber = $('#formContactFaxNumber').val();
  var contactemail = $('#formContactEmail').val();
  var website = $('#formWebsite').val();
  var address = $('#formAddress').val();
  var postcode = $('#postCode').val();

    var arrayData = {"name":name,"regno":regno,"charityinfo":charityinfo,"searchimprove":searchimprove,"finantialaid":finantialaid,"contactname":contactname,"contactphonenumber":contactphonenumber,"contactfaxnumber":contactfaxnumber,"contactemail":contactemail,"website":website,"address":address,"postcode":postcode};
    console.log(name);

    $.ajax({  
  url: "test.php",  
  type: "POST",  
  dataType: "json",  
  contentType: "json",  
  async: false,
  data: arrayData,
 success : function(response) {                            
                    alert(response);            
              },
              error: function(){
                    alert("error");
              }
  }); //End AJAX
```

My PHP Code:

```
<?php
$return = $_POST;
echo json_decode($return);
?>
```

Comment: $_POST is array. use $return = $_POST['data'];

Comment: the datd is already decoded. You can print them out using `print_r($_POST)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, collect your form data in 1 step, serialize it as json:

```
var arrayData = $('#my_form_id').serialize();
```

If you post your data, you should post the appropriate post variable name with it. Add some more decriptive error handling:

```
$.ajax({  
      url: "/test.php",  
      type: "POST",  
      data: 'mydata = ' + arrayData,
      success : function(response) {                            
        alert(response);            
      },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(thrownError);
      }
    });
```

And then on the php side pick it up:

```
$mydata = $_POST['mydata'];
$arrayData = json_decode($mydata);
var_dump($arrayData);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You haven't encoded the data you are sending as JSON. You are passing an object to jQuery and allowing it to encode it (as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`). You need to [encode your data as JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and pass a string to `data:`.
2. `json` is not a content-type, `application/json` is.
3. `$_POST` is populated from `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`, it doesn't contain the raw post request. You need to use [`php://input`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731297/file-get-contentsphp-input-or-http-raw-post-data-which-one-is-better-to) to get that.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't need to create json yourself

use `JSON.stringify()` function function to create `JSON`

or you can also use  the jquery `serialize()` function

```
var arrayData=$("FORMID").serialize();
$.ajax({  
  url: "test.php",  
  type: "POST",  
  dataType: "json",  
  contentType: "json",  
  async: false,
  data: arrayData,
  .....
```

and decode this json serverside using `json_decode()` function