# Alternatives to file_get_contents('php://input') - cURL proposed, can't get it to work

Tags: php, curl

For when web-hosts don't allow file_get_contents (either directly, or by allow_url_fopen). I want to put together a list of alternatives. Can anyone offer suggestions? I found that cURL could be used, but the code below doesn't return anything in $output.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"php://input" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```

Answer (score -1):

File_get_contents alternative (CURL):

```
<?php

function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Set curl to return the data instead of printing it to the browser.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}

?>
```

Note: not made by me, found this on the internet some weeks ago.

Comment: It worked for me. Just call it like this `$something = file_get_contents_curl('http://some-site.com/');`

Comment: Oops my bad but I found a question about the same 'topic', http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731297/file-get-contentsphp-input-or-http-raw-post-data-which-one-is-better-to , maybe it's use full.

Comment: Ok well that doesnt help me, but thanks for replying.