# null answer with POST data CodeIgniter 2.1.3

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, file-get-contents

I have this problem.

I used this sentence to get post info in CodeIgniter 1.7.2 and it works fine

```
function function1(){
    $input_data = json_decode(trim(file_get_contents('php://input')), true);
    $info = str_replace( '"', '', json_encode($input_data['info']));
}
```

My input json is this:

```
{
    "info":"hello!"
}
```

But when I used these same lines in CodeIgniter 2.1.3 it doesn't work. I used `echo $info` but my answer is `null`. Anyone can help me? Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is not CI related. It's most PHP concepts.
Your mistake is probably that you're trying to access something that doesn't exist.

What is the point to use `file_get_contents('php://input')`? Can't you just use `$this->input->post()`, or the `upload`class? (in CI context)?

Anyway, check what do you get in `file_get_contents()`, `var_dump`ing it. I'm pretty sure that your `NULL` comes from `$input_data` assignment statment, so you're fetching the JSON in the wrong way at first.

Comment: The reason is because I'm using a controller as a web service, so in a post I saw that it works in a previous work.

Comment: Ok now you put me in context. What do you obtain if you `var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'))` ??

Comment: With var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input')); Y got this -> string(0) ""

Comment: Then there's the `NULL` you're getting (`json_decode` on an empty string). Problem is in the input.
Check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731297/file-get-contentsphp-input-or-http-raw-post-data-which-one-is-better-to

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a Controller as a WebService and It works fine in a previous work. So, I tested with this

```
function test(){
   $m = $this->input->post('key');
   echo $m;     
}
```

and I'm sending a POST JSON data as follow:

```
{
'key':'hello!"'
}
```

and now I receive nothing. Some else?