# Having issues with reading and displaying a JSON object in PHP

Tags: php, json, swift

I've been attempting to read in a `JSON` dictionary from Swift through PHP and display the results.

So far, I have been able to send the dictionary in the form `{location: "North America", Name: "Me"}` to the server correctly using a `POST` method.

**My problem is reading in the content and displaying it.**

My PHP code is:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$value = json_decode($json);

var_dump($value);
?>
```

Whenever I run the script, I get a `500` server error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why wont you use `$_POST` / `$_GET` to get the content? `file_get_contents` uses the local filesystem, that is probably the cause of your problem.

Comment: Server error log would be helpful too.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2731431/946170

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [php.net](http://php.net): php://input is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data".  Did you check your request headers?