# Are PHP “php://input” and $_POST mutually exclusive?

Tags: php, ajax, parsing, post

**DUPLICATE NOTE**: *This is not IMO a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post) because I lookaed at that first and did not find an answer to the question there. If you do find it, please let me know exactly where.*

In PHP, as we know, the *superglobal* `$_POST[]` is an array that will contain the result of parsing incoming HTTP request body for the mime types of either

- *application/x-www-form-urlencoded* (standard content type for simple form-posts) or
- *multipart/form-data-encoded* (mostly used for file uploads)

If our client is sending anything else as a request we need to take care of the parsing ourselves by using the string returned from `file_get_contents('php://input');`.

Now here is my question; let's say that I don't know what mimetype my request contains. **Can I use `$_POST` and `php://input` interchangeably**? Or to be more specific, will reading from `php://input` interfere with the population of `$_POST[]`, or will accessing `$_POST[]` somehow disrupt or disable `php://input`?

Comment: have you seen/read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post - Read it if you haven't. If it answers the question, I'll mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, in fact I was looking at that when forming my question because even though both the question and answers there are excellent I felt that the topic of my question had been elegantly avoided, and was important enough to warrant it's own question on S.O.

Comment: No problemo Lennart, *cheers*

Comment: Have a look on it. might be satisfies your doubt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731297/file-get-contentsphp-input-or-http-raw-post-data-which-one-is-better-to

Comment: I hereby express my utmost frustration over having this question marked as a duplicate. It is not a duplicate because the question is not answered in the other link :)