# Converting many POST request to strings using $_SERVER

Tags: php

For the get request we can convert the query string to string using,

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

But for the post method above method don't work. Is there another method which will make the post query to the string.

Comment: POST data is in  `$_POST`.

Comment: `json_encode($_REQUEST)` will get you json serialized get,  post and cookie parameters.

Comment: @vp_arth http://stackoverflow.com/a/2143042/208809

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are running PHP from the command line, PHP will populate the [superglobal arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) `$_GET` and `$_POST` (among others) with the parsed query values and respective post body values. It will do that automatically, so there is no reason why you would `parse_str` on the query string like you show.

Quoting the [PHP Manual for `$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method when using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` as the HTTP Content-Type in the request.

This is the prefered way of accessing POST data. However, you can also get access to the raw post body, [via the `php://input` stream or `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731297/file-get-contentsphp-input-or-http-raw-post-data-which-one-is-better-to) (the latter is deprecated in PHP 5.6.0, and REMOVED as of PHP 7.0.0).

Quoting the [PHP Manual on input streams](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php):

> `php://input` is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data from the request body. In the case of POST requests, it is preferable to use `php://input` instead of `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` as it does not depend on special php.ini directives. Moreover, for those cases where `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` is not populated by default, it is a potentially less memory intensive alternative to activating `always_populate_raw_post_data`. `php://input` is not available with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.