# Upload Previewed Image to Mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have been able to successfully select an image and preview on iframe.  I would like now to be able to take that previewed Image and upload into mysql table column as a Blob.  I know that it is not in my best interest to upload images into database, but for my project it is in my best interest and as there will only be a limited amount of images to ever be uploaded.  This is the code at where I am at.  I have been able to upload image using another form but just cannot combine the scripts to work. Here is a working example of what i have so far, now i would like to take that previewed image and upload
     [SampleApp](http://www.i-audit-jci.com/previewimageaug8)

IFRAME

```
<img src="" id="image">
<input id="input" type="file" onchange="handleFiles()">
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
var img = document.getElementById("image");
var width = 400;
function handleFiles() {
var filesToUpload = document.getElementById('input').files;
var file = filesToUpload[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
img.onload = function() {
if (this.naturalWidth > width) {
this.width = width;
}
}
img.src = e.target.result;
}
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
</script>
```

CONNECTION

```
$con = mysqli_connect('****','*****','****','DBNAME') or die('Unable To connect');
$sql = "insert into images (image) values(?)";
```

Comment: Look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest with https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData for the javascript, and then look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731297/file-get-contentsphp-input-or-http-raw-post-data-which-one-is-better-to for php

Comment: is there away to take my whole script and create a php script that i can post on my server and be able to capture the previewed image

Comment: i have placed a SampleApp above to understand what i am trying to acchomplish.

Comment: Sorry wrong link in previous comment http://stackoverflow.com/a/38829952/267540

Comment: thanks for the input, i would like to store images in another folder and add hyperlink to image in column, but was having hard time trying to retrieve images from link in Navicat