# how to received array post from angularJS to codeigniter in controller and save into database

Tags: angularjs, ajax, codeigniter-3

how to received a data from post array in angular JS into Codeigniter ?, below is my code

controller in Codeigniter

```
     public function add_data_chat()
            {


            $datas = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);



                $message                 =   $datas ["message"];
                $payment_step         =   $datas ["payment_step"];
                $negotiation_price    =  $datas ["negotiation_price"];
                $room_id                 =  $datas["room_id"];
                $member_id           =  $datas["member_id"];


         $sql="INSERT INTO dash_chat_documentation (message, payment_step, negotiation_price, room_id, member_id, chat_time) VALUE ('$message','$payment_step',$negotiation_price,'$room_id',$member_id,now())";

            $data= $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

ANGULARjs

```
$scope.tambahData = function(){

            databaru = {

                message:$scope.databaru.message,
                payment_step:'regular_chat',
                negotiation_price:'0',
                room_id:'123',
                member_id:'01'
             };

            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '<?php echo base_url('dashboard/workspace/add_data_chat') ?>',
                headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},

                data: $scope.databaru
                }).success(function (hasil) { $scope.data.push({
                    message: $scope.databaru.message,
                    chat_time: $scope.databaru.chat_time
               });
                 $scope.databaru.message='';
                });
};
```

the problem why i cannot received a data from angularJS to codeigniter, please help

Comment: [Is your `Content-Type` set correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2731380/594235)

Comment: im not really sure, because i got from other solution in here, do you have any suggestion? because im really stuck right now.                                 $datas = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE); this code like not work @Sparky

Comment: Did you click the link in my first comment?

Comment: wow it works!!!! tahnk youu @Sparky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Just look like codeigniter request by angular js get json object

   ```
    $params = file_get_contents('php://input');
      if (empty($params)) {
          $parmete2 = $_POST;
      } else {
          $parmete2 = json_decode($params, true);
      }
   ```

   2. angular js post

   -

   function(form_data){

   ```
            $scope.submitted = true;

            $scope.reg = form_data;

            var fd = new FormData();

            var file = $scope.fileToUpload;

            fd.append('file',file);

            fd.append('first_name',$scope.reg.first_name);

            fd.append('last_name',$scope.reg.last_name);

            $http.post(API_URL+"user_update_profile", fd, {

               transformRequest: angular.identity,

               headers: {'Content-Type': application/json}
              })
              .success(function(res){
                   console.log(res);
              })
              .error(function(err){
                   console.log(err);
              });
      }
   ```

Comment: Welcome and please do my post like @denindra resky