# Not getting post value from file_get_contents('php://input')

Tags: php

I am having an issue when I am using a post request on an PHP file and I am passing simple keys and values to post. For example say `key = productId` and `value = 123`.

```
<?php

$data_back = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

return $data_back;
```

I am receiving nothing. Please assist.

Comment: We are not getting the post inputs like this `file_get_contents('php://input') `

Comment: @KubiRoazhon maybe you are not, but I am : when request parameters are passed as JSON body of the POST request, instead of codified in the URL.

Comment: @Aditya : how are you invoking this PHP script ?  show that code too.

Comment: Maybe he should simply try to var_dump the $_REQUEST variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check how is your request created. It must be POST and [php://input is not available for enctype="multipart/form-data"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2731431/135837)
2. Problem may be `json_encode()` receiving invalid JSON. Check for `json_decode` error and/or check if the output from `file_get_contents('php://input')` is really empty.

Answer (score -1):

in PHP file you can catch post request variabile just using $_POST array.

```
<?php

$data_back = $_POST;

return $data_back;

?>
```