# Receive JSON payload with ZEND framework and / or PHP

Tags: zend-framework, http-headers, json

I'm receiving a JSON payload from a webservice at my site's internal webpage at /asset/setjob. The following is the JSON payload being posted to /asset/setjob:

> [{"job": 
>        {"source_filename": "beer-drinking-pig.mpg",
>         "current_step": "waiting_for_file",
>         "encoding_profile_id": "nil",
>         "resolution": "nil",
>         "status_url": "http://example.com/api/v1/jobs/1.json",
>         "id": 1,
>         "bitrate": "nil",
>         "current_status": "waiting for file",
>         "current_progress": "nil",
>         "remote_id": "my-own-remote-id"}}]

This payload posts one time to this page. The page is not meant for viewing but parsing the JSON object for the id and current_status so that I can insert it into a database. I'm using Zend framework.

HOW DO I receive this payload in Zend? Do I $_GET['json']? $_POST['job']? None of these seem to work. I essentially need to assign this payload to a php variable so that I can then manipulate it.

I've tried:

> $jsonStrGet = var_dump($_GET);
>     $jsonStrPost = var_dump($_POST);

And I've tried:
$response = $this->getResponse();
  $body = $response->getBody();

> Blockquote

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: What was the output of $jsonStrGet = var_dump($_GET); $jsonStrPost = var_dump($_POST); ?

Comment: Check the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813487/how-to-post-json-to-php-with-curl

Answer (score 39):

It is possible to get payload data this way (inside your action method):

```
$body = $this->getRequest()->getRawBody();
$data = Zend_Json::decode($body);
```

The $body will contain your raw JSON string: [{"job": {"source_filename": ...}] and $data variable will contain decoded JSON data passed in payload.

Comment: ZF2: `$this->request->getContent();`

Answer (score 4):

Following up on what @Saeven said above for Zend Framework 2 you would have use $request->getContent() with \Zend\Json\Json::decode.  Here's an example I used for testing.

```
<?php

namespace Rsvp\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;

class RsvpController extends AbstractActionController{

    public function getAccessTokenAction() {
        $request = $this->getRequest();

        $result = array('status' => 'error', 'message' => 'There was some error. Try again.', 'isXmlHTTP' => $request->isXmlHttpRequest());

        if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
             $data = \Zend\Json\Json::decode($request->getContent());

            if(!empty($data->token)){
                $result['status'] = 'success';
                $result['accessToken'] = '1234';
               $result['message'] = '';
            }
        }
    
        return new JsonModel($result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of how you use ZF here, but to access to request parameters, you need to use

```
$this->getParams() or $this->getParam('yourvar');
```

[(See manual)](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.request.html)

in your controller.

Then, use [`Zend_Json::decode($var);`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.json.basics.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking, but to convert a JSON string into an object, use `Zend_Json::decode($foo)`?