# php rest api call

Tags: php, json, api

This is the only official documentation available for the Halo: Reach stats API. If you have questions, read this group's forum and/or wiki to get assistance.

This is a collection of methods to access the Halo: Reach game, player, and file information. They are available as a .NET 4.0 WCF service with three endpoints. To enforce consistency between the different protocols, all three endpoints follow this interface. Each protocol may be accessed through its associated endpoint located at http://www.bungie.net/api/reach/. The available endpoints are reachapijson.svc for JSON REST queries, reachapixml.svc for XML REST queries, and reachapisoap.svc for legacy SOAP XML support. Note that the examples given in this documentation use the REST syntax, documentation for SOAP Web services is not available. Consult your development environment's (Visual Studio) documentation for more information. No official support is available other than this documentation.

Available Methods
Note: "identifier" is always your application's identifier string that you registered under your account settings. This is used to ensure we know who's application is making the statistics call. Unregistered applications will not work.

GetGameMetadata(System.String)

This function returns no dynamic data, but rather is used to translate resource ids into full resources (medals, commendations, etc.)

Parameters

identifier: Your application's identifier string.

Return Value
An object containing several dictionaries that can be used to translate the various ids of resources into more detailed versions.

Example: http://www.bungie.net/api/reach/reachapijson.svc /game/metadata/ {identifier}

how can i use the php to call this api and display data

thanks for help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to post JSON to PHP with curl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813487/how-to-post-json-to-php-with-curl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how can i use the php to call this api
>   and display data

[cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

[JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php)