# How to call RESTful WCF-Service from PHP

Tags: php, json, wcf, rest

I'm trying to send an request to an Self-Hosted WCF-Service with REST in PHP.
I want to send the object to the WCF service as an JSON Object.
I did not get it running yet.
Has anyone an example how to call the service out of PHP?

This is the Operation contract (The method is a POST method):

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    void Method1(AnObject object);
```

The best working Code in PHP is the following:

```
$url = "http://localhost:8000/webservice/Method1?object=$object"; 
    $url1 = parse_url($url);

// extract host and path:
$host = $url1['host'];
$path = $url1['path'];
$port = $url1['port'];

// open a socket connection on port 80 - timeout: 30 sec
$fp = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 30);

if($fp)
{
    // send the request headers:
    fputs($fp, "POST $path HTTP/1.1\r\n");
    fputs($fp, "Host: $host\r\n");

    fputs($fp, "Content-type: application/json \r\n");
    fputs($fp, "Content-length: ". strlen($object) ."\r\n");
    fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
    fputs($fp, $object);
//
//  $result = ''; 
//  while(!feof($fp)) {
//          // receive the results of the request
//          $result .= fgets($fp, 128);
//  }
}
else { 
    return array(
        'status' => 'err', 
        'error' => "$errstr ($errno)"
    );
}

// close the socket connection:
    fclose($fp);
```

But this code does not send the object. In Debugging-Mode the Object is "null". I just see, that it enters the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution for my own problem:

```
$url = "http://localhost:1234/service/PostMethod"; 
$jsonObject = json_encode($transmitObject);

    $options = array(
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Content-Length:".strlen($jsonObject)));

    $defaults = array( 
        CURLOPT_POST => 1, 
        CURLOPT_HEADER => 0, 
        CURLOPT_URL => $url, 
        CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => 1, 
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1, 
        CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE => 1, 
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 4, 
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $jsonObject
    ); 

    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt_array($ch, ($options + $defaults)); 
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you perform a POST on a WCF Rest service the raw request should look as below:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/webservice/Method1 HTTP 1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost

{"object":{"ObjectId":1,"ObjectValue":60}
```

Assuming your `AnObject` looks as below:

```
[DataContract]
public class AnObject 
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ObjectId {get;set;}
    [DataMember]
    public int ObjectValue {get;set;}
}
```

From your php code you are trying to send the object as a query string which is not going to work. Rather build your code to add the json string to the http body.

Use some tools like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) or [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org) where you can intercept the request/response and inspect them. You can use them even to test the WCF Rest service by building a raw request.

Find some links that might be helpful:

1. [Create a php Client to invoke a REST Service](http://www.sematopia.com/2006/10/how-to-making-a-php-rest-client-to-call-rest-resources/)
2. [php rest api call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712183/php-rest-api-call)

Comment: It was a nice hint, but not the solution. I did fix it now. See my following post.

Answer (score 0):

I got work "der_chirurg" solution by adding parameter next to $path as below

original:

```
$url = "http://localhost:8000/webservice/Method1?object=$object"; 
fputs($fp, "POST $path HTTP/1.1\r\n");
```

changed to:

```
fputs($fp, "POST $path**?object=$object** HTTP/1.1\r\n");
```

and 
instead of in the $url

```
$url = "http://localhost:8000/webservice/Method1
```

Finally:

```
 url = "http://localhost:8000/webservice/Method1";
        $url1 = parse_url($url);
    // extract host and path:
    $host = $url1['host'];
    $path = $url1['path'];
    $port = $url1['port'];

    // open a socket connection on port 80 - timeout: 30 sec
    $fp = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 30);

    if($fp)
    {
    // send the request headers:
    fputs($fp, "POST $path?value=test HTTP/1.1\r\n");
    fputs($fp, "Host: $host\r\n");

    fputs($fp, "Content-type: application/json \r\n");
    fputs($fp, "Content-length: ". strlen($param) ."\r\n");
    fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $jsonData = json_encode($object, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
 $options = array(
     'http'=>array(
            'method'        =>  "POST",
            'ignore_errors' =>  true,
            'content'       =>  $jsonData,
            'header'        =>  "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
                                "Content-length: ".strlen($jsonData)."\r\n".
                                "Expect: 100-continue\r\n" .
                                "Connection: close"
            )
        );

        $context = stream_context_create($options);
        $result = @file_get_contents($requestUrl, false, $context);
```

Very important is JSON format.