# POST JSON over CURL with basic authentication

Tags: json, api, http, post, curl

I am using Curl from the command line to debug a small web api I am working on. The web api expects basic authentication and a JSON object as input (POST). Currently this basic authentications works fine:

```
curl -i --user validuser:70e12a10-83c7-11e0-9d78-0800200c9a65 http://example.com/api.php
```

but I also want to send a JSON object as a POST request:

```
curl -i --user validuser:70e12a10-83c7-11e0-9d78-0800200c9a65 -X POST -d '{"person":{"name":"bob"}}' http://example.com/api.php
```

I'm getting a 400 Bad Request response with the above command, any ideas on how I bundle a json object in this POST request?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Try it with:

```
curl -i --user validuser:70e12a10-83c7-11e0-9d78-0800200c9a65 -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -d '{"person":{"name":"bob"}}' http://mysite.com/api.php
```

I've removed the `json=` bit in the body content.

Alternatively, this post might be helpful: [How to post JSON to PHP with curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813487/how-to-post-json-to-php-with-curl)

Answer (score 6):

```
curl --request POST \
  --url http://host/api/content/ \
  --header 'authorization: Basic Esdfkjhsdft4934hdfksjdf'
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use

```
$person = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

instead use

```
$person = $_POST['person'];
```

And if you're using curl from the command-line this is the syntax for wanting to POST json data:

```
curl -d 'person={"name":"bob"}'
```

Comment: From the various threads i've read on this topic, file_get_contents("php://input"), appears to be the standard way of retrieving the raw body of the post request.

Comment: @LBNerdBard define "standard".

Comment: I should have said 'most sensible' instead of 'standard', because I am not processing multipart form data but rather a single string entity

Comment: If this method is possible, could you produce the full (basic authenticated) curl command corresponding to it, i have changed the api to listen for $_POST['person'] - This question is not just how to accept JSON data, but how to construct the fully authenticated curl POST command