# Parse Postmark Bounce hook in PHP

Tags: php, api, hook

I am using Postmark to send emails.
But postmark allows you to set a URL to process bounced emails.
I want to use this, but don't know how to get and handle the data.

My API works but I don't know how to retrieve the data postmark sends to my API.

```
<?php

class BackendBillingAPI
{
    public static function postmarkBounceHook()
    {
        $log = new SpoonLog('custom', PATH_WWW . '/backend/cache/logs/billing');

        // logging when we are in debugmode
        if(SPOON_DEBUG) $log->write('Billing post (' . serialize($_POST) . ') triggered.');
        if(SPOON_DEBUG) $log->write('Billing get (' . serialize($_GET) . ') triggered.');
        if(SPOON_DEBUG) $log->write('Billing _REQUEST (' . serialize($_REQUEST) . ') triggered.');

    }
}
```

Any thoughts/ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to parse the json data inside the POST, and you can't rely on _POST apparently (since this is not a multipart form, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/813512/305019) for more info)

Here's a simple code that grabs a few parameters from the postmark bounce and generates an email. You can grab the parameters and do whatever else you need to of course

```
<?php
$form_data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

// If your form data has an 'Email Address' field, here's how you extract it:     
$email_address = $form_data->Email;
$details = $form_data->Details;
$type = $form_data->Type;

// Assemble the body of the email...                                              
$message_body = <<<EOM
Bounced Email Address: $email_address
Details: $details
Type: $type
EOM;
if ($email_address) {
    mail('ENTER YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS',
         'Email bounced!',
         $message_body);
}
?>
```