# How to POST JSON Data With PHP cURL?

Tags: php, json, rest, curl

Here is my code,

```
$url = 'url_to_post';
$data = array(
    "first_name" => "First name",
    "last_name" => "last name",
    "email"=>"email@gmail.com",
    "addresses" => array (
        "address1" => "some address",
        "city" => "city",
        "country" => "CA",
        "first_name" =>  "Mother",
        "last_name" =>  "Lastnameson",
        "phone" => "555-1212",
        "province" => "ON",
        "zip" => "123 ABC"
    )
);
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$ch=curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("customer"=>$data_string));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
    array(
        'Content-Type:application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)
    )
);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

And at other page, I am retrieving post data.

```
    print_r ($_POST);
```

Output is

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 18 Jun 2012 07:58:11 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.6
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

Array ( )
```

So, I am not getting proper data even at my own server, it's empty array. I want to implement REST using json as at http://docs.shopify.com/api/customer#create

Comment: Aren't You missing converting `$data` to `$data_string` using `json_encode()`??? Do not see this line of code...

Comment: Sorry i didn't write here but in my code i wrote `code` $data_string=json_encode($data); `code` and how to write code in comments?in comments i can't write line break and so how to write code?

Answer (score 322):

You are POSTing the json incorrectly -- but even if it were correct, you would not be able to test using `print_r($_POST)` ([read why here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/813510/445295)).  Instead, on your second page, you can nab the incoming request using **`file_get_contents("php://input")`, which will contain the POSTed json**.  To view the received data in a more readable format, try this:

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")),1).'</pre>';
```

In your code, you are indicating `Content-Type:application/json`, but you are not json-encoding all of the POST data -- only the value of the "customer" POST field.  Instead, do something like this:

```
$ch = curl_init( $url );
# Setup request to send json via POST.
$payload = json_encode( array( "customer"=> $data ) );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
# Return response instead of printing.
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
# Send request.
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
# Print response.
echo "<pre>$result</pre>";
```

*Sidenote: You might benefit from using [a third-party library](http://docs.shopify.com/api/libraries/php) instead of interfacing with the Shopify API directly yourself.*

Comment: so you dont have to explicitly specify it is POST request? Its known because CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS is set?

Comment: where was this answer when I was looking for it all week last week?
Now I find it way after I had to figure out myself!

Comment: Sidenote: If you send JSON and expect JSON as response, then some APIs require setting the response type as well `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json', 'Accept:application/json'));` (otherwise you may send JSON, but get XML as answer).

Answer (score 105):

```
$url = 'url_to_post';
$data = array("first_name" => "First name","last_name" => "last name","email"=>"email@gmail.com","addresses" => array ("address1" => "some address" ,"city" => "city","country" => "CA", "first_name" =>  "Mother","last_name" =>  "Lastnameson","phone" => "555-1212", "province" => "ON", "zip" => "123 ABC" ) );

$postdata = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r ($result);
```

This code worked for me. You can try...

Comment: The correct JSON encoding would be have an array like this  `$data = array("customer"=> array("first_name" => "First name", "last_name" => "last name", ... `

Answer (score 25):

Replace

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("customer"=>$data_string));
```

with:

```
$data_string = json_encode(array("customer"=>$data));
//Send blindly the json-encoded string.
//The server, IMO, expects the body of the HTTP request to be in JSON
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
```

---

I dont get what you meant by "other page", I hope it is the page at: 'url_to_post'. If that page is written in PHP, the JSON you just posted above will be read in the below way:

```
$jsonStr = file_get_contents("php://input"); //read the HTTP body.
$json = json_decode($jsonStr);
```

Comment: Why would you assume that? If he's putting the data in the 'customer' field, he must be doing so for a reason, no?

Comment: Yes, thanks, I missed that part. But he, IMO, is doing it wrong. I will update my answer with it.

Comment: None of the above solutions work to get json data in php file :(

Answer (score 14):

Please try this code:-

```
$url = 'url_to_post';

$data = array("first_name" => "First name","last_name" => "last name","email"=>"email@gmail.com","addresses" => array ("address1" => "some address" ,"city" => "city","country" => "CA", "first_name" =>  "Mother","last_name" =>  "Lastnameson","phone" => "555-1212", "province" => "ON", "zip" => "123 ABC" ) );

$data_string = json_encode(array("customer" =>$data));

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo "$result";
```

Answer (score 9):

First,

1. always define certificates with CURLOPT_CAPATH option,
2. decide how your POSTed data will be transfered.

## 1 Certificates

By default:

- `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST == 2` which "*checks the existence of a common name and also verify that it matches the hostname provided*" and
- `CURLOPT_VERIFYPEER == true` which "*verifies the peer's certificate*".

So, all you have to do is:

```
const CAINFO = SERVER_ROOT . '/registry/cacert.pem';
...
\curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, self::CAINFO);
```

taken from a working class where `SERVER_ROOT` is a constant defined during application bootstraping like in a custom classloader, another class etc.

**Forget things like** `\curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);` or `\curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);`.

Find `cacert.pem` [there](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) as seen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987857/what-exactly-is-cacert-pem-for) question.

## 2 POST modes

There are actually 2 modes when posting data:

- the data is transfered with `Content-Type` header set to `multipart/form-data` or,
- the data is a urlencoded string with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding.

In the first case you pass an **array** while in the second you pass a **urlencoded string**.

### `multipart/form-data` ex.:

```
$fields = array('a' => 'sth', 'b' => 'else');
$ch = \curl_init();
\curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
\curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
```

### `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` ex.:

```
$fields = array('a' => 'sth', 'b' => 'else');
$ch = \curl_init();
\curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
\curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, \http_build_query($fields));
```

### `http_build_query`:

Test it at your command line as

```
user@group:$ php -a
php > $fields = array('a' => 'sth', 'b' => 'else');
php > echo \http_build_query($fields);
a=sth&b=else
```

The other end of the POST request will define the appropriate mode of connection.

Answer (score 6):

Try like this:

```
$url = 'url_to_post';
// this is only part of the data you need to sen
$customer_data = array("first_name" => "First name","last_name" => "last name","email"=>"email@gmail.com","addresses" => array ("address1" => "some address" ,"city" => "city","country" => "CA", "first_name" =>  "Mother","last_name" =>  "Lastnameson","phone" => "555-1212", "province" => "ON", "zip" => "123 ABC" ) );
// As per your API, the customer data should be structured this way
$data = array("customer" => $customer_data);
// And then encoded as a json string
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$ch=curl_init($url);

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_string,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type:application/json', 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)))
));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The key thing you've forgotten was to json_encode your data. But you also may find it convenient to use curl_setopt_array to set all curl options at once by passing an array.

Comment: -1. Check the API here: http://api.shopify.com/customer.html#create. The body that server expects in JSON, not urlencoded-json. Check my answer, no need to use `array(..)` in `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Comment: Yes, as I said he is sending it wrong. Passing an `array(..)` to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` will urlencode the JSON too.

Comment: Anyway, i tried many times with different code but i was not able to do in json now i did successfully in xml.

Answer (score 2):

Try this example.

```
<?php 
 $url = 'http://localhost/test/page2.php';
    $data = array("first_name" => "First name","last_name" => "last name","email"=>"email@gmail.com","addresses" => array ("address1" => "some address" ,"city" => "city","country" => "CA", "first_name" =>  "Mother","last_name" =>  "Lastnameson","phone" => "555-1212", "province" => "ON", "zip" => "123 ABC" ) );
    $ch=curl_init($url);
    $data_string = urlencode(json_encode($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("customer"=>$data_string));


    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $result;
?>
```

Your page2.php code

```
<?php
$datastring = $_POST['customer'];
$data = json_decode( urldecode( $datastring));

?>
```