# Heroku app crashes, but logs don't display error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I looked at the other similar questions, and none of the solutions worked for me.
I'm using rails, ruby > 2.2. I precompiled my assests beforehand, and followed the steps on the heroku website for deployment.
Heroku restart or Heroku open yields the following logs

```
T13:23:51.140722+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tranquil-reef-67177.herokuapp.com request_id=ddb61e34-f755-4c7b-b6e7-fbb7d2d2c545 fwd="99.99.45.37" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-08-16T13:26:09.989021+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting               2017-08-16T13:26:12.914632+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 16431 -e production`                                                                                   2017-08-16T13:26:18.084985+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-08-16T13:26:17.981060+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                         2017-08-16T13:26:17.981072+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-08-16T13:26:17.981118+00:00 app[web.1]: >>>> A cacert.pem bundle could not be downloaded.       2017-08-16T13:26:17.981452+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2017-08-16T13:26:17.981454+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options       2017-08-16T13:26:17.981454+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.1.3 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:16431                                                                                    2017-08-16T13:26:17.981457+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2017-08-16T13:26:18.097040+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed               2017-08-16T13:28:52.442323+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:setup` by user smantri7@gatech.edu                                                                          2017-08-16T13:28:58.768622+00:00 heroku[run.9307]: Awaiting client
2017-08-16T13:28:58.793376+00:00 heroku[run.9307]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:setup`
2017-08-16T13:28:58.977883+00:00 heroku[run.9307]: State changed from starting to up                 2017-08-16T13:29:06.107123+00:00 heroku[run.9307]: State changed from up to complete
2017-08-16T13:29:06.088150+00:00 heroku[run.9307]: Process exited with status 1                      2017-08-16T13:29:25.187872+00:00 heroku[run.6090]: Awaiting client
2017-08-16T13:29:25.261306+00:00 heroku[run.6090]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:create`
2017-08-16T13:29:25.463655+00:00 heroku[run.6090]: State changed from starting to up                 2017-08-16T13:29:21.565730+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:create` by user smantri7@gatech.edu
2017-08-16T13:29:33.024076+00:00 heroku[run.6090]: State changed from up to complete
2017-08-16T13:29:33.008825+00:00 heroku[run.6090]: Process exited with status 1
2017-08-16T13:31:57.967030+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:push` by user smantri7@gatech.edu
2017-08-16T13:32:01.731122+00:00 heroku[run.8862]: Awaiting client
2017-08-16T13:32:01.787259+00:00 heroku[run.8862]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:push`
2017-08-16T13:32:01.976994+00:00 heroku[run.8862]: State changed from starting to up
2017-08-16T13:32:09.014212+00:00 heroku[run.8862]: State changed from up to complete
2017-08-16T13:32:08.996819+00:00 heroku[run.8862]: Process exited with status 1                      2017-08-16T13:33:08.827762+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-08-16T13:33:12.246286+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 40298 -e production`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here: >>>> A cacert.pem bundle could not be downloaded. You need to check an issue with cacert.pem

Comment: Thank you! Would you have any idea where the problem would be? Is it simply a missing cacert.pem?

Comment: Start by reviewing this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987857/what-exactly-is-cacert-pem-for