# Laravel broadcasting on Pusher, failed job queue

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin, pusher

I built a chatroom API that uses Laravel events and listeners,broadcasting via pusher and listening for those public and private channels via laravel echo and Vue.

However where I became stuck is after having to reinstall wamp64 and move the Laravel application to the newly installed wamp64/www/ path, composer was updated all dependencies are within the new folder as needed, however the issue occurs with event and job queue .A failed job ever time I trigger the event.

I would like to note that my Pusher account is working due to the listeners working while in the chatroom. The broadcasting/job queue it where it gets stuck.(Subscription is being made to the chatroom channel,however it isn't receiving messages from the event/broadcasting).

**Below is the the failed job exception.**

```
Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastException in C:\wamp64\www\nathanreynolds\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Broadcasting\Broadcasters\PusherBroadcaster.php:117
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp64\www\nathanreynolds\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent.php(48): Illuminate\Broadcasting\Broadcasters\PusherBroadcaster->broadcast(Array, 'App\\Events\\NewC...', Array)
#1 [internal function]: Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent->handle(Object(Illuminate\Broadcasting\Broadcasters\PusherBroadcaster))
#2 C:\wamp64\www\nathanreynolds\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 C:\wamp64\www\nathanreynolds\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#4 C:\wamp64\www\nathanreynolds\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#5 C:\wamp64\www\nathanreynolds\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(572): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#6 C:\wamp64\www\nathanreynolds\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher.php(94): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#7 C:\wamp64\www\nathanreynolds\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->Illuminate\Bus\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent))
#8 C:\wamp64\www\nathanreynolds\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent))
#9 C:\wamp64\www\nathanreynolds\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher.php(98): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#10 C:\wamp64\www\nathanreynolds\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler.php(49): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->dispatchNow(Object(Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent), false)
#11 C:\wamp64\www\nathanreynolds\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job.php(83): Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler->call(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), Array)
#12 C:\wamp64\www\nathanreynolds\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Worker.php(327): Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job->fire()
#13 C:\wamp64\www\nathanreynolds\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Worker.php(277): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->process('database', Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#14 C:\wamp64\www\nathanreynolds\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Worker.php(118): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->runJob(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), 'database', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#15 C:\wamp64\www\nathanreynolds\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand.php(102): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->daemon('database', 'default', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#16 C:\wamp64\www\nathanreynolds\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand.php(86): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->runWorker('database', 'default')
#17 [internal function]: Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->handle()
#18 C:\wamp64\www\nathanreynolds\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#19 C:\wamp64\www\nathanreynolds\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#20 C:\wamp64\www\nathanreynolds\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#21 C:\wamp64\www\nathanreynolds\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(572): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#22 C:\wamp64\www\nathanreynolds\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php(183): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#23 C:\wamp64\www\nathanreynolds\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php(255): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#24 C:\wamp64\www\nathanreynolds\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php(170): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#25 C:\wamp64\www\nathanreynolds\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(901): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#26 C:\wamp64\www\nathanreynolds\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(262): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#27 C:\wamp64\www\nathanreynolds\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(145): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#28 C:\wamp64\www\nathanreynolds\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Application.php(89): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#29 C:\wamp64\www\nathanreynolds\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(122): Illuminate\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#30 C:\wamp64\www\nathanreynolds\artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#31 {main}
```

**Payload**

```
{"displayName":"App\\Events\\NewChat","job":"Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler@call","maxTries":null,"timeout":null,"timeoutAt":null,"data":{"commandName":"Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastEvent","command":"O:38:\"Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastEvent\":7:{s:5:\"event\";O:18:\"App\\Events\\NewChat\":4:{s:4:\"chat\";a:5:{s:3:\"rid\";s:1:\"1\";s:5:\"owner\";s:18:\"frezknow@gmail.com\";s:4:\"body\";s:9:\"tigfdhugs\";s:10:\"created_at\";s:19:\"2019-02-16 18:04:33\";s:4:\"user\";O:8:\"stdClass\":2:{s:4:\"name\";s:15:\"Nathan Reynolds\";s:3:\"img\";s:49:\"uploads\/frezknow@gmail.com\/1550337650_DSC0140.jpg\";}}s:6:\"status\";s:6:\"public\";s:4:\"user\";O:45:\"Illuminate\\Contracts\\Database\\ModelIdentifier\":4:{s:5:\"class\";s:8:\"App\\User\";s:2:\"id\";i:1;s:9:\"relations\";a:0:{}s:10:\"connection\";s:5:\"mysql\";}s:6:\"socket\";N;}s:10:\"connection\";N;s:5:\"queue\";N;s:15:\"chainConnection\";N;s:10:\"chainQueue\";N;s:5:\"delay\";N;s:7:\"chained\";a:0:{}}"}}
```

Apparently I have a connection issue, which is odd due to the fact that I can connect with no issue in my Vue component.?

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/Broadcasters/PusherBroadcaster.php

line 117 states

```
        throw new BroadcastException(
        is_bool($response) ? 'Failed to connect to Pusher.' :    $response['body']
    );
```

Comment: cacert.pem file was needed as well as it needed to be referenced, this was what was holding the pusher connection  back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the follow file (cacert.pem) not being in my PHP_versionx.x.x.x/extras/ssl/ folder as well as the file needed to be referenced in the php.ini file, it could not connect to PUSHER.

Resources 
 https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/16478  Please read [shadoWalker89]'s answer.
 [What exactly is cacert.pem for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987857/what-exactly-is-cacert-pem-for)