# Sending POST data using cURL, by scanning QR code

Tags: php, curl, qr-code

I'm trying to pass some data (`JSON`) to another page by scanning a QR code.
The page where the data is send to, contains a `HTML` form. I want to use that form as a last chance to correct the data before sending it to the database.

I found here at S.O. a way to pass the data using cURL: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15643608/2131419)

QR code library:
http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net

I use the QR code execute this function:

```
function passData () {
    $url = 'check.php';
    $data = array('name' => 'John', 'surname' => 'Doe');
    $ch = curl_init( $url );

    # Setup request to send json via POST.
    $payload = json_encode($data);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));

    # Return response instead of printing.
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

    # Send request.
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    # Print response.
    return $result;
}
```

### Create QR code:

```
QRcode::png(passData(), $tempDir.'007_4.png', QR_ECLEVEL_L, 4);
echo '<img src="'.$tempDir.'007_4.png" />';
```

### Check.php

```
<?php $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true); ?>

<form method="post" action="handle.php">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $data['name'];?>" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="surname" value="<?php echo $data['surname'];?>" /><br />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

### Problem:

I can pass the data to check.php, but it's returning plain text instead of a useable `HTML` form.

[image]

Hope someone can help!

**EDIT**

**Some clarification:**

What I actually want is, to scan the QR code, which executes the passData() function. Then the 'QR code scanner app', needs to open a browser, which shows `check.php` with the form **AND** the passed data as the `values` of the `input` fields.

Now, I get only the response of `check.php` (plain text).
When I pass an `URL` instead of the `passData()` function like:
`QRcode::png("http://www.google.com", $tempDir.'007_4.png', QR_ECLEVEL_L, 4);`

The app asks if I want to go to http://www.google.com.

Comment: Well you need something to render the html, a browser or a webview

Comment: Thats true. But now, I execute this cURL function (`passData()`) by scanning the QR code, but when I do `QRcode::png('http://www.google.com', $tempDir.'007_4.png', QR_ECLEVEL_L, 4);` it shows me the google website. What I want, is to pass the data to `check.php` and then show `check.php` with the passed variables as the `input` values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QR codes cannot execute code. The only executable type of data you can put in a QR code is a URL. That is why using google.com as a URL opens a web browser to that URL. The QR code itself does not render anything.

What your code is doing is fetching the `check.php` page when the QR code is generated and then storing the output as the raw data. It isn't a webpage, it is a string like you are seeing in your question. You may be able to pass a javascript URL similar to a bookmarklet but its execution would depend on the QR code reader being used.

**bookmarklet example**

```
<?php

function passData() {
    // javascript code in a heredoc, you may need to url encode it
    return <<<JS
        javascript:(function() {
          //Statements returning a non-undefined type, e.g. assignments
        })();
JS;
}
```

A better way to do it would be to have your QR code generate a URL like: `http://your-site.com/check.php?name=John&surname=Doe` and host `check.php` on your machine. You can use the `$_GET` data to populate your form and then use javascript to automatically post it as [Jah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2088945/jah) mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I know it can be done by using GET, but are there any POST alternatives?

Comment: @JK87 No. You can try using a javascript url bookmarklet to make a POST request. You cannot make a local HTML form or do a direct POST with a QR code.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way but you can do something like this.

**Check.php:**

```
 <?php
$data = '<form method="post" action="handle.php">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="name" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="surname" value="surname" /><br />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>';

$html = str_replace(PHP_EOL, ' ', $data);
$html = preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', "\n", $html);
$html = preg_replace('/[ \t]+/', ' ', $html);
$html = str_replace('> <', '><', $html);
?>
<div id="placeholder">
    Write HTML here
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function write_html(id,data){
        var formHtml = data;
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = formHtml;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: can i see a print screen of it?

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear enough. I edited it. Hopefully it is now ;)