# Converting a cURL command to PHP

Tags: php, curl

I have the following cURL command:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" -H "TC: 000000" -H "ST: 000000" -X POST -d '[{"Param1" : "Value1", "Param2" : "Value2"} ]' http://www.somesaasprovider.com/
```

It works fine when I'm running it in the terminal and I get the expected output.

However, when I try to use the same command but adapted to PHP, I get no result.

The PHP version looks like this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$ch = curl_init('http://www.somesaasprovider.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '[{"Param1" : "Value1", "Param2" : "Value2"}]');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',        
    'TC' => '000000',
    'ST' => '000000')
);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$response = json_decode($response);

print_r($response);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use curl_error($ch) after curl_exec to see the last error.

Comment: I did that, but it didn't show any error.

Comment: Have your tried setting a timeout first with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);`  and then see the last error?

Comment: Yes, still no error.

Comment: You may need to encode your post fields.
Take look at this post <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079135/how-to-post-json-data-with-php-curl>

Comment: That was my first attempt. I used `json_encode()` just like in the link you've posted. It didn't work so I used the version I have posted.