# JSON API returning error although parameters are being sent

Tags: php

I'm sending a request to a JSON API system (http://help.solarwinds.com/backup/documentation/Content/service-management/json-api/login.htm) using PHP:

```
$base = 'https://cloudbackup.management/jsonapi';

$vars = array(
    "jsonrpc" => "2.0",
    "method" => "Login",
    "params" => array(
        "partner" => "partner",
        "username" => "username",
        "password" => "pass",
    ),
    "id" => "1",
);

$ch = curl_init( $base );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$output = json_decode($response, true);
```

But its returning this array in `$output`

```
Array
(
    [error] => Array
        (
            [code] => -32700
            [data] => 119
            [message] => Parse error: Failed to parse request body: * Line 1, Column 1
  '--------------------------' is not a number.

        )

    [id] => jsonrpc
    [jsonrpc] => 2.0
)
```

I cannot work out why it's returning an error, because I'm sending the correct parameters that it says in the docs.

Can someone point me in the right direction or if I have missed something?

Comment: "I'm sending a request to a JSON API" So where is the JSON in your request?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to POST JSON Data With PHP cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079135/how-to-post-json-data-with-php-curl)

Comment: Can you post what $response is before you try to decode it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the content-type to application/json as curl is likely defaulting to sending it as `x-www-form-urlencoded`

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
```

also JSON-encode your array:

```
$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($vars);
```

Full refactored sample:

```
$base = 'https://cloudbackup.management/jsonapi';

$vars = array(
    "jsonrpc" => "2.0",
    "method" => "Login",
    "params" => array(
        "partner" => "partner",
        "username" => "username",
        "password" => "pass",
    ),
    "id" => "1",
);

$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData);
$ch = curl_init( $base );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json')); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$output = json_decode($response, true);
```

Comment: Just made an additional edit - your $vars data needs to be `json_encode`ed

Comment: oh! "puts head in hands" - its been a long day. thanks so much

Comment: No problem!  Glad to help.  If my answer works, can you kindly accept it as the correct answer? :)