# Get JSON Return Status From json_encode PHP POST Request

Tags: php, json

I need to send data using `json_encode`. I just get the reference below:

```
$key = 'my_key';
$url = 'url';

$data = array (
   'username' => 'user', 
   'api_key' => 'key',
   'orderid' => 'ORDERID-0001'
   'shipper_name' => 'SENDER',
   'shipper_contact' => 'SENDER',
   'shipper_phone' => 'sender_phone',
   'shipper_addr' => 'sender address',
   'origin_code' => 'CITYCODE',
   'receiver_name' => 'RECEIVER',
   'receiver_phone' => 'receiver_phone',
   'receiver_addr' => 'receiver address',     
   'receiver_zip' => 'receiver zip',
   'destination_code' => 'DESTCODE',
   'receiver_area' => 'SDA001',
   'qty' => '1',
   'weight' => '1',
   'goodsdesc' => 'TESTING!!',
   'servicetype' => '1',
   'insurance' => '50000',
   'orderdate' => '2019–2-10 22:02:00',
   'item_name' => 'hat',
   'cod' => '200000',
   'sendstarttime' => '2017–2-10 08:00:00',
   'sendendtime' => '2017–2-10 22:00:00',
   'expresstype' => '1',
   'goodsvalue' => '1000',
);

$data_json = json_encode(array('detail'=>array($data)));
$data_request = array (
    'data_param'=>$data_json, 
    'data_sign'=> base64_encode(md5($data_json.$key))
);
```

I was send the data above using Postman but it returned "Parameters can not null". Then I try using curl but the response HTTP 500.

Can someone here tell me the best practice to get best response?

By the way this is sample response if the code above is success:

```
{
   "success":true,
   "desc":"request success",
   "detail":
   [
      {
         "orderid" : "ORDERID-0001",
         "status" : "Error",
         "reason" : "username or api key wrong!",
      }
      {
         "orderid" : "ORDERID-0002",
         "awb_no" : "AWBJNT-001"
         "status" : "Success",
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: If that is the code you're using, one reason for the problems is that your $data array is missing comma after orderid causing syntax error.

Comment: If https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079135/how-to-post-json-data-with-php-curl solves your problem then this can be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @yasoh ow okay it's my fault, after give a comma after orderid i got nothing, just white screen.

Comment: @NigelRen thanks for the link, but it's a bit confused, maybe I need more explanation...

Comment: _“Can someone here tell me the best practice to get best response?”_ - best practice would be to actually properly analyze and debug your problem, _instead of_ asking for “best practices” at such a point. (Following best practices is not wrong of course; but reading up on them would be your responsibility IMHO, outside of SO.) _“I was send the data above using Postman”_ - you mean you tried to send it? Or are you the receiver of such a request, and don’t know how to work with it? _Show us_ what you actually tried, instead of just telling us that you tried something.

Comment: @04FS thanks for the suggestion. Problem solved now, I get right good answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First set header as below**

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

**Then generate response and echo it.**

```
$response[] = array(
                        'status' => 'true',
                        'desc' => 'request success',
                        'detail'=> $data,
                    );

echo json_encode(array('response' => $response));
```

Note: I added basic params here, you can add other details as per your need.

Comment: Good but not's enough to get response data. Thanks for the reference I get the detail of `data_sign`