# Pass Variable Via JSON with CURL

Tags: php, json, curl

How to pass a form variable to another page via JSON? I had create two php file with file naming page_login.php and login.php. However when running login_post.php, the $json value unable pass to login.php

page_login.php:

```
$email = test@gmail.com;
$password = 123;

$json = array('email' => $email, 'password' => hash("sha256",$password));
$json = json_encode($json);

$ch = curl_init();      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://localhost/login.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);                                                                                                           
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

login.php:

```
$json=json_decode($_REQUEST["json"],true);
print $json;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to POST JSON Data With PHP cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079135/how-to-post-json-data-with-php-curl)

Comment: Need to set Content-Type header and then read `php://input` on the receiving end.

Comment: Or, `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['json'=>$json]);` on the sending end. But then you're not passing JSON, just plain old POST value.

Comment: Or, just skip the JSON encoding; on the receiving end look at `$_POST['email']`. Any of these three options will solve your problem.

Comment: May i know why if i send the json data to localhost login.php, its work but if send to another server don't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

page_login.php

```
$email = "test@gmail.com";
$password = "123";

$json = array('email' => $email, 'password' => hash("sha256",$password));
$json = json_encode($json);

$ch = curl_init();      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://localhost/login.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array("json" => $json)));                                                                                                           
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

echo $server_output;
```

login.php

```
$json=json_decode($_REQUEST["json"],true);
foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ": " . $value;
    echo "<BR>";
}
```

Comment: May i know why if i send the json data to localhost login.php, its work but if send to another server don't work?

Comment: It should work, have you tried getting a response from the server login.php and outputting it in the page_login.php just to verify if the server receives the request?

Comment: ya, but it just show a blank page, my login php: $json=json_decode($_REQUEST["json"],true);
print_r($json);

Comment: @Ichida i did update the page_login.php, can you run that file and replace the `CURLOPT_URL` to the new server

Comment: On your login.php, can you do this`echo "<pre>"; var_dump($_REQUEST); echo "</pre>"; $json=json_decode($_REQUEST["json"],true); print_r($json);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193741/discussion-between-jayson-garcia-and-ichida).