# Php api calls another using curl - Data lost

Tags: php, api, curl

I've created two php apis. One of them (API-1) needs to call the other (API-2) through post method. But when the second api is called,, the data is lost.

**Website architecture**
[image: Website architecture]

**CODE**

**API 1 : http://mylocalsite.com/auth/register**

```php
// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

// get posted data
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$url = "http://mylocalsite.com/user/create";
$client = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
$response = curl_exec($client);
curl_close($client);
```

**API 2 : http://mylocalsite.com/user/create**

```php
// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

// get posted data
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

// display data
var_dump($data);
```

**Data sent**

```
{
    "username" : "anonymous_api",
    "password" : "secret123!",
    "firstname" : "anonymous_api",
    "lastname" : "anonymous_api",
    "email" : "anonymous_api@bookingpro.com",
    "role" : "USER"
}
```

**Expected data**

```
{
    "username" : "anonymous_api",
    "password" : "secret123!",
    "firstname" : "anonymous_api",
    "lastname" : "anonymous_api",
    "email" : "anonymous_api@bookingpro.com",
    "role" : "USER"
}
```

**Actual data**

```php
"NULL\n"
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Are those two API's using the same application, or are `/auth` and `/user` two different apps that will live on different locations?

Comment: You should also pass the post data "as is" (which seems to be serialized json?) instead of doing json_decode() before adding it to the post fields. [Here's a post with a lot of answers/examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079135/how-to-post-json-data-with-php-curl)

Comment: Why not use $_POST instead of json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")); ?

Comment: Also why make two api calls? Can't you execute the endpoint without using curl?

Comment: They are two different applications but in the same server.

Comment: _“Why not use $_POST”_ - because PHP will not populate $_POST, if the Content-Type of the request was not either `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`.

Answer (score 0):

It works. Thank you for your comments And many thanks to @Magnus Eriksson. Indeed the error was that the data is decoded before sending to the second api.