# PHP curl long link with quotes and white spaces

Tags: php, curl

Need to access REST api from php using cURL.
This i a rest link:

```
http://username:password@172.16.59.225:8042/tools/find -d '{"Level":"Study","Expand":false,"Query":{"StudyDate":"20191226-20200324"}}'
```

as you see a lot of " and white space.

I have tried to prepare string manually like this:

```
$url = "http://172.16.59.225/tools/find -d '{\"Level\":\"Study\",\"Expand\":false,\"Query\":{\"StudyDate\":\"20191226-20200324\"}}'";

and pass password using: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
```

I have used `urlencode()` and `curl_escape` and nothing works. At the same time, this link works perfectly by using it with curl in Linux cmd.

Is it doable?

Comment: I think this is will work [Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079135/how-to-post-json-data-with-php-curl)

Comment: but how to pass -d parameter surrounded by white spaces  ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, `--data` or `-d` param is to `sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server` [Source](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-raw)

```
$url = 'http://172.16.59.225/tools/find';
$postdata = '{"Level":"Study","Expand":false,"Query":{"StudyDate":"20191226-20200324"}}';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r ($result);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot both of you. The "-d" was a problem but i also used the json_encode feature.

Comment: just replace with this `$postdata = json_encode($your_array)`