# Translate array with google translator

Tags: php, laravel, api, google-translate

I use below PHP code in Laravel to translate one sentence or paragraph from one input field:

```
    $apiKey = env('GOOGLE_TRANSLATOR_API');
    $url = env('GOOGLE_TRANSLATOR_LINK') . $apiKey . '&q=' . rawurlencode($name) . '&target='.$language;
    $handle = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($handle);
    $responseDecoded = json_decode($response, true);
    
    return $responseDecoded['data']['translations'][0]['translatedText'];
```

and it works perfectly fine.

But now I have two input fields (name and description) and I want to translate both of those fields using one API call and show the results individually.

**EDIT**

I have tried to use array in the API request as below:

```
    $apiKey = env('GOOGLE_TRANSLATOR_API');
    $url = env('GOOGLE_TRANSLATOR_LINK') . $apiKey . '&q=' . array('sentence one', 'sentence two) . '&target='.$language;
    $handle = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($handle);
    $responseDecoded = json_decode($response, true);
    
    return $responseDecoded['data']['translations'][0]['translatedText'];
```

But I get *Array to string conversion* error.

Comment: @M.Eriksson but in this link it says that google can translate using json, but it is not in php https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/translating-text#translate_translate_text-drest

Comment: PHP can send anything you want it to in the curl request. So if you want to send JSON, then send JSON.

Comment: And since they give a cURL example in that documentation, you can use https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/ to quickly get a PHP version of that cURL request, to get you started. It's not really clear why you're stuck,

Comment: @ADyson can you write it as answer.

Comment: Well it's not really a solution is it? More just a statement of what's possible. I just commented to point out to you that all the information you need to solve this yourself is already available to you.

Comment: @ADyson I tried but failed to solve it.

Comment: in that case you need to show us what you tried and explain what specifically went wrong compared to what you expected to happen. "failed" isn't an error message or a meaningful problem description. You can [edit] the question with any updates :-)

Comment: Thanks for the update. Making an array in PHP doesn't, by itself, generate JSON (but it's likely to generate a PHP warning about converting arrays to strings). Also you're not putting the data in the request body. You seem to have guessed, rather than following any of the instructions in the documentation you found, or taking my advice and converting their cURL example into PHP. Or you can use the PHP Google library, as per the example below.

Comment: @ADyson anyways I didn't get your point.

Comment: What specifically didn't you understand?

Comment: @ADyson your comments.

Comment: As I said, what _specifically_ from what I wrote were you uncertain about? We're not going to get anywhere unless you can clarify that.

Comment: @ADyson this is not clear "PHP can send anything you want it to in the curl request. So if you want to send JSON, then send JSON. – ". If possible write your idea in code.

Comment: Well I didn't think it was necessary to write it all out because there are lots of examples of that process online already, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079135/how-to-post-json-data-with-php-curl. Lots more here: https://www.google.com/search?q=php+curl+send+json

Answer (score 1):

[1](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/HEAD/translate/src/v3_translate_text.php)Installing the Basic Client Libraries [Client library PHP](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/setup#installing_client_libraries)

```
composer require google/cloud-translate
```

and in your code

```
    use Google\Cloud\Translate\V3\TranslationServiceClient;

$translationServiceClient = new TranslationServiceClient();

/** Uncomment and populate these variables in your code */
// $text = 'Hello, world!';
// $textTwo = 'My name is John':
// $targetLanguage = 'fr'; // your lang
// $projectId = '[Google Cloud Project ID]';
$contents = [$text, $textTwo];
$formattedParent = $translationServiceClient->locationName($projectId, 'global');

try {
    $response = $translationServiceClient->translateText(
        $contents,
        $targetLanguage,
        $formattedParent
    );
    // Display the translation for each input text provided
    foreach ($response->getTranslations() as $translation) {
        printf('Translated text: %s' . PHP_EOL, $translation->getTranslatedText());
    }
} finally {
    $translationServiceClient->close();
}
```

[View Code in Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/HEAD/translate/src/v3_translate_text.php)