# problem sending POST request through curl

Tags: php, curl

I have a problem in the code in which the API is not receiving the command for set_system_time, I don't know if it could be an error in the way of passing the parameters, follow the code used and the api documentation, in case anyone can help me in this case.

date.php (connects to the api, takes the session token and uses it for the second request)

```
<?php
$cookie="cookie.txt";
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://192.168.5.23/login.fcgi');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{ \"login\": \"admin\", \"password\": \"senha\"}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie); 

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$session1 = json_decode($result);
$sessao = $session1->{'session'};

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
//curl_close($ch);

///////////////
echo $sessao;
$ch1 = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.5.23/set_system_time.fcgi?session=$sessao");

curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{ \"day\": \"1\", \"month\": \"2\", \"year\": \"2020\", \"hour\": \"21\", \"minute\": \"20\", \"second\": \"22\" }");
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie); 

curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

//$result = curl_exec($ch1);

curl_close($ch1);



?>
```

as the api shows that the information has to be passed, their example is in js, but I'm trying to do it using curl from PHP

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/set_system_time.fcgi?session=" + session,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        day: 10,
        month: 12,
        year: 1983,
        hour: 21,
        minute: 30,
        second: 00
    })
});
```

I made the same request, taking the token and executing another api command, but this request didn't need to pass parameters, maybe the problem is in this part but I couldn't identify it.

Comment: What happens? Any errors? Does the login step work?  My guess is you have a problem in how you are constructing/sending the JSON.  Searching for "*php curl postfields json*" turns up some examples which might help, eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079135/how-to-post-json-data-with-php-curl

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to include the API documentation?

This is an invalid JSON string.

```
$jsn = '{ \"day\": \"1\", \"month\": \"2\", \"year\": \"2020\", \"hour\": \"21\", \"minute\": \"20\", \"second\": \"22\" }';
```

I tested the above $jsn string by converting it to an array:

```
$array = json_decode($jsn);
var_export($array);
echo "\n";
    switch (json_last_error()) {
        case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
            echo ' - No errors';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
            echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
            echo ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
            echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
            echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
            echo ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
        break;
        default:
            echo ' - Unknown error';
        break;
    }
```

The above returns

```
NULL 
- Syntax error, malformed JSON
```

Whereas this string works:

```
$jsn = '{ "day": "1", "month": "2", "year": "2020", "hour": "21", "minute": "20", "second": "22" }';
```

I would never build JSON manually.

```
$jsn = json_encode(array (
  'day' => '1',
  'month' => '2',
  'year' => '2020',
  'hour' => '21',
  'minute' => '20',
  'second' => '22',)
);
echo $jsn;
```

The above returns:`{"day":"1","month":"2","year":"2020","hour":"21","minute":"20","second":"22"}`

Comment: Nice debugging explanation, but I don't think an answer should ever suggest manually constructing a JSON string (unless there are some strange special reasons) ...  Just create an array and use `json_encode()`.

Comment: @Don'tPanic  I would NEVER build JSON manually.   I ALWAYS use json_encode() even on the very simple JSON.  I updated my answer.  Thanks.