# How to decode a json encoded array after passing it through an API

Tags: php, json, lumen

So, I have an array I need to encode and send via an API.

```
$data = array(
            'tracking_no' => $process_list->tracking_no,       
            'status' => $status_id
        );
$data1 = (json_encode($data));
```

Now, I send it through curl to another site.

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => env('MILON_MELA_URL').'api/request/mm-process-data',
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
          CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
          CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data1,
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'ApiAuthorization: bearer '.$responsetoken->token,
            'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          ),
));
        
$response1 = curl_exec($curl);
```

But for some reason, the result comes out as an array like this:

```
[{"tracking_no":"MM-43E9","status":"25"}]
```

Obviously, the function json_encode does not work here since the project thinks it is dealing with an array. So now we are stuck with a json_encoded string that thinks itself an array but cant be read. Now what?
And yes, before anyone asks, I did search how to decode an array inside two brackets. It always leads me to multidimensional arrays which this is not..........

Comment: Add this: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));   CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS is great for data1=val1&data2=val2...... etc..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079135/how-to-post-json-data-with-php-curl

Comment: Thanks............that took less than a second.............I really have a lot left to learn