# Problem accessing POST from a request in PHP

Tags: php

I try to mock a foreign API for testing purposes. However, when I build the endpoint, I cannot access the data sent via post request.

This is the request, that works totally fine with the original API (created with postman)

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => 'https://myEndpointUrl.com/endPoint',
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
            "custAddrZip":"12345",
            "custAddrCountry":"de",
            "custGender":"m",
            "products":["123456"],
            "shopDocumentId": "4567890"
            }',
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'X-API-Key: AUTHORIZATION_KEY'
        ),
    )
);

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

on the endpoint side there is currently just:

```
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

which returns

```
array(0) {
}
string(0) ""
```

where I expect to get the Json string instead.

How can I access the data sent in POST?

Comment: It seems `CURLOPT_POST` is missing? Not sure if `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` can replace it?

Comment: I assume you do a `curl_exec()` somewhere?

Comment: Well, the exact same call works with the original API. I don´t know how they do it, so they can access the data.

Comment: It might be that the content is there in the post, but PHP might require the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content header? OK, this is all just speculation. I haven't tested anything.

Comment: This looks like a good read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079135/how-to-post-json-data-with-php-curl

Comment: @KIKO Software "Content-Type: application/json" is required by the original API.

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you, but there the problem seems to be on the requesting side. The Request works perfectly with the original APIs endpoint. My problem seems to be at my mockup API´s  receiving endpoint.

Comment: Check what `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` contains. Often such issues are caused by (unintended) redirects, which make the client follow up with a GET request, and thereby losing the POST data.

Comment: Given what I know now, I expect `file_get_contents("php://input")` to work, but it doesn't. Did you have a good look in your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools)? What does the network tab there report?

Comment: @CBroe this returns a GET.  Thank you, this seems to be the reason for the problem.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware how would browser dev tools be relevant here? The request is going from PHP to another PHP script. Browser isn't involved

Comment: @LeviPike in that case it might be worthwhile checking if your mock endpoint has any URL rewrite rules in place, or anything like that.

Comment: When I run your code I see `{
"custAddrZip":"12345",
"custAddrCountry":"de",
"custGender":"m",
"products":["123456"],
"shopDocumentId": "4567890"
}` from the `file_get_contents("php://input")`

Comment: But to see it, I did `file_put_contents('debug/dump.txt', file_get_contents("php://input") );` and then looked at the dump.txt file the browser is not involved here

Comment: The `$_POST` was empty

Comment: Hi all, @CBroe ´s hint was correct. That was what caused the issue. The endpoint redirected the request as a GET, removing the POST. I could already solve it with this hint. We can close this discussion here, I just do not know how :D.