# PHP Curl POST data is not sent

Tags: php, curl

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://www.test.com/dosomething \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic value_for_basic_authentication \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "type": "limit",
  "quantity": "10",
  "price": „1“,
  "strictValidate": false
}'
```

This is the command which is working fine on command line

This should be now the php script snippet where I want to send the same request in php and curl. From Verbose mode I see, that the post data is never sent.  I know the part with the lines can be done easier

```
            
   $line0 =  "type: limit";
   $line1 =  "quantity: 10";
   $line2 =  "price: 1";
   $line3 =  "strictValidate: false }" ;




  $params = array(
                        $line0,
                        $line1,
                        $line2,
                        $line3
                         );



    $headers = array(
        "Accept: application/json",
        $auth
        );
    
    $paramsJSON = json_encode ( $params );
    
    
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $paramsJSON );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

    
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
```

Here some part of the log output where is visible that post data is not sent
Logfile from Server

There the request is working

- ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1

> POST /api/v2/createorder HTTP/1.1
> Host: [www.test.com/dosomething](http://www.test.com/dosomething)
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> accept: application/json
> Authorization: Basic MmEwN2MxZTBjZDY5ZmQ3NGEyYTVmNzFiMjI0MDdkN2M6MjQ5N2IzMGU3MTRhYjNmODg1MTZiMWExODRkYWViY2JhMmU1OWQ4MmVlZjI1Nzg5
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 154

- upload completely sent off: 154 out of 154 bytes

With my PHP Script request is not working

- ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1

> POST /api/v2/createorder  HTTP/1.1
> Host: [www.test.com/dosomething](http://www.test.com/dosomething)
> Accept: application/json
> Authorization: Basic MmEwN2MxZTBjZDY5ZmQ3NGEyYTVmNzFiMjI0MDdkN2M6MjQ5N2IzMGU3MTRhYjNmODg1MTZiMWExODRkYWViY2JhMmU1OWQ4MmVlZjI1Nzg5
> Content-Length: 169
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

- upload completely sent off: 169 out of 169 bytes

Difference is Content-Type: application/json -> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
no idea how to change it it "Content-Type: application/json" in my PHP code

Comment: You need to call [curl_init](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php) to set up the request and then [curl_exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) to actually make it.

Comment: Which line of PHP do you think is sending the request?

Comment: Yes.. I know I need a curl_init and also a curl_exec() at the end..   as I wrote.. the data is sent to the web server, but the post_data $params is missing.     I wrote a code snippet.. as the rest seems clear to me :-)

Comment: You should send it as JSON. `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($params));`. But why are there multiple lines? `$params = ['type' => 'limit', 'quantity' => 10, ...];` would be the thing to go.

Comment: _"as I wrote.. the data is sent"_ What you wrote was, _"the post data is never sent."_ Please clarify. Post the rest of the code. Post the output of the curl debug. Post the contents of the `$line*` variables. If the problem is that you're having trouble processing the post on the server side, post the code that handles the request. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079135/how-to-post-json-data-with-php-curl).

Comment: Is your request received by the server?

Comment: 1) Yes.   request is received by server ( see the last lines as log output from client to server communication             tried with json_encode. same problem.. post data is never sent..   I tried to add more code to make it more clear.   and theoretically I know what I have to send, because from bash command line the curl request works

Comment: `-H 'Authorization: Basic value_for_basic_authentication \ ` is missing a closing `'`. Incorrect quotes in `"price": „1“,`

Comment: That is a copy past error.. as I told .l.  the first command on command line ois working fine..   I need a solution for the php script

Comment: "_That is a copy past error_" Are you saying copy/paste didn't work, you copied something but pasted something different?

Comment: that is not really helpful :-)    as I told .. the first command is working.. seems the copy - paste to the application here changed ist..   I need solution for the php code :-)

Comment: Excellent. Now, what is the HTTP status of the response?

Comment: array(1) {
  ["error"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["code"]=>
    int(400)
    ["message"]=>
    string(11) "Bad Request"
    ["description"]=>
    string(22) "Missing input 'type'"

as I told..   the problem is that the post data is not sent

Comment: Found some differences in log file ( see in code above at the end ). anyone any idea how to chang that?

Answer (score 2):

To produce a JSON object, `$params` should be an associative array, not an array of `key: value` strings.

```
$params = [
  "type" => "limit",
  "quantity" => "10",
  "price" => "1",
  "strictValidate" => "false"
];
```

Answer (score 0):

The last answer solved the issue!!!

```
$params = [
"type" => "limit",
"quantity" => "10",
"price" => "1",
"strictValidate" => "false"
];
```

plus json_decode $params

solved the issue :-)

Many thanks to all who answered