# PHP decode JSON POST

Tags: php, json

I"m trying to receive `POST` data in the form of JSON. I'm curling it as:

```
curl -v --header 'content-type:application/json' -X POST --data '{"content":"test content","friends":[\"38383\",\"38282\",\"38389\"],"newFriends":0,"expires":"5-20-2013","region":"35-28"}' http://testserver.com/wg/create.php?action=post
```

On the PHP side my code is:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

    $content    = $data->{'content'};
    $friends    = $data->{'friends'};       // JSON array of FB IDs
    $newFriends = $data->{'newFriends'};
    $expires    = $data->{'expires'};
    $region     = $data->{'region'};
```

But even when I `print_r ( $data)` nothing gets returned to me. Is this the right way of processing a `POST` without a form?

Comment: Why aren't you using `json_decode($_POST)`?

Comment: @hohner when I try that, it gives me the error `json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given `

Comment: @hohner Because `$_POST` is assumed to be URL encoded data.

Comment: @Chris Debug in more detail. `var_dump` the POST content before decoding it. It just looks like invalid JSON to me.

Comment: What happens if you set the content-type in the cURL command: `-H "Content-Type:application/json"`?

Comment: @deceze `var_dump` gave me an empty array

Comment: @hohner Isn't that the same as `--header "content-type:aplication/json"` ? I'm already doing that

Comment: What happens when you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/813510/427992

Comment: @hohner still doesn't return anything

Comment: It baffles me that this was closed. It's a totally generic question - how to parse an HTTP POST string into JSON in PHP. Anyway a way that works for me is: 
$inputContents = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, true);

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The JSON data you're submitting is not valid JSON.

When you use ' in your shell, it will not handle \" as you suspect.

```
curl -v --header 'content-type:application/json' -X POST --data '{"content":"test content","friends": ["38383","38282","38389"],"newFriends":0,"expires":"5-20-2013","region":"35-28"}'
```

Works as expected.

```
<?php
$foo = file_get_contents("php://input");

var_dump(json_decode($foo, true));
?>
```

Outputs:

```
array(5) {
  ["content"]=>
  string(12) "test content"
  ["friends"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "38383"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "38282"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "38389"
  }
  ["newFriends"]=>
  int(0)
  ["expires"]=>
  string(9) "5-20-2013"
  ["region"]=>
  string(5) "35-28"
}
```