# How do I receive a json data passed as argument from android application?

Tags: php, json

I used to decode a json string stored in a variable. Now i've come across a situation where a php file is passed a set of json data.

I'm not aware of how to get the data and then decode it to php array.

please do not give answers like

```
$variable = '{ "data1" : "value1" }';
```

I've used this before.

//Edit

Also I'm not asking how to encode a php array to json.

Thanks.

Comment: Mmmh. https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=php+decode+json `->` http://no1.php.net/json_decode. But you also mention that you don't know how to *get* the data. Well, how is the Android app trying to transfer the data to the PHP script? Without more context, we cannot really help you.

Comment: Hi Felix, the data coming from android is simple { "username": "value1", "password" : "value2" } I need to catch this data in PHP and then decode them to process further.

Comment: Ok, so you know how to get the data. As I showed, googling for `php decode json` would have given you the answer you needed. Didn't you search before?

Comment: @Felix thank you so much. I got the answer here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914628/php-decode-json-post

Comment: So, the information you needed was `file_get_contents("php://input")`? That's why I wanted to know *"how is the Android app trying to transfer the data to the PHP script"*.

Comment: Sorry Felix for not providing proper information. The UI did not provide enough information!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the PHP function [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/json_encode)

```
<?php
$var = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2);

echo json_encode($var);
?>
```

You can Decode in same way by same way [json_decode](https://www.php.net/function.json-decode)

```
$var= '{"car": 5}';

$obj = json_decode($var);
echo $obj->{'car'};
```

Comment: I don't want to encode data from array to json. I asked how to decode the json data passed from android application!