# $_POST is empty even though CONTENT_LENGTH is correct

Tags: php, post, nginx, multipart

I've got an **HTTP POST** pointed at two different places.

The *first location is handled by a thirdparty solution*, so I can't see how they're handling the data (which they must be because the values are getting through and I'm seeing results).

In *my location*, I have an NGINX server (which has never had any problems before with lots of use). I am using **php to read the POST data**, and I expect the content to be in the `$_POST` variable as the POST is `$_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"] => "multipart/form-data"`

But, even though the type and the `$_SERVER["CONTENT_LENGTH"]` are correct, I'm getting nothing in my `$_POST`, `$_REQUEST`, and when checking `file_get_contents('php://input')` there is nothing inside either.

The body is a very small **json lump (<1k)**. Always an array of objects.

To see what's in the arrays I used `echo json_encode( array( "GET" => $_GET, "POST" => $_POST, "REQUEST" => $_REQUEST, "SERVER" => $_SERVER ) )`

I've run out of ideas of what to check now.

the entry `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` has a strange garbling possibly due to the path delimiters?

Comment: `php://input` is not available with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. courtesy: [SOFPOST-2731297](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731297/file-get-contentsphp-input-or-http-raw-post-data-which-one-is-better-to/2731431#2731431).
Btw, How did you check the value inside `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to post JSON to PHP with curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813487/how-to-post-json-to-php-with-curl/813512#813512) lead me to the solution:

*Don’t forget to send it as `application/json`*

Once I did that, the data came through in the body. This helps me, but I'm still curious as to why the third party receiver can handle the data as it was.