# php get POST data without key

Tags: javascript, php, post, xmlhttprequest

I'm building a little web-app where I'd like the users to be able to upload files, I'm using FormData to do so, /

```
<input id="fileInput" type="file">

var formData = new FormData()
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function () {window.resp = this}
request.open("POST", "upload.php");
request.send(formData);
```

But I have no idea how to get the data using PHP.
I know you can normally do

```
$_POST["KEY"]
```

But in this case I'm not using a key because the data isn't a string.

I've searched for quite some time now and came across the following things

```
print_r($_POST) // returned an empty array
var_dump($_POST) // returned an empty array
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and it's probably just some thing you have to know, but I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks in advance.

EDIT 
Turns out you can just get the file using the

```
$_FILES
```

global, huge thanks to @tobias K!

SOURCES:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: Did you check what is being sent in the network tab of the browsers DevTools? Also, try `$_FILES`.

Comment: [POST method uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to post JSON to PHP with curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813487/how-to-post-json-to-php-with-curl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are posting raw data, you can get it in PHP by

```
$rawData = file_get_contents("php://input");
```