# formdata.append a combined associative array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to append the data from two associative arrays I have so I can send it to my php file to then write to the server.
I combined my two arrays by doing the following:

```
var allInputs = {... reqfields,... otherfields};
```

Up until here I am getting all the values I need and I am seeing them on my console but I don't know how to use the formData.append() for these types of arrays.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Append this object to your FormData as a JSON string:

```js
const reqfields = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const otherfields = { c: 3 };
const allInputs = {... reqfields,... otherfields};

const formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append( 'your_field_key', JSON.stringify(allInputs) );

/*
// then you can send it to your server
fetch( server_url, {
  method: "POST",
  body: formdata
 });
*/
// for SO demo we just log the request's body as text
new Response( formdata ).text()
  .then( console.log );
```

And then on your server side you can retrieve it from the multipart data using the field key you used and simply parse it:

```php
<?php 

  if ( isset($_POST["your_field_key"]) ) {
    $fields = json_decode($_POST["your_field_key"]);
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the signature of formData.append [is given by](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append):

```
formData.append(name, value);
```

(*you could also add a filename as a third argument)

Assuming the `reqFields` and the `otherFields` are objects of the form:

```
{
  fieldName1: response1,
  fieldName2: response2,
  ...
}
```

you could use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to iterate over the properties and call formData.append on each.

```
    const allInputs = {...requiredFields, ...otherFields};

    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(allInputs)) {
       formData.append(key, value);
    }
```

*Note that Object.entries isn't natively supported in Internet Explorer. You can also use `Object.keys(allInputs).forEach(...)` to [iterate over all of the keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) in allInputs. [There are other ways, too.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Comment: I see, that makes sense , so on the  php side decoding the values would be as simple as $dcData = json_decode($_POST['formData']);? Given after I send it through the request =  new Request.JSON({... Or is there a certain way of accessing the variables inside the array?

Comment: if you've sent along the formData with a post request, you should be able to retrieve individual field values on the php side by doing: 
`$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
`

Comment: Posting formData via an XMLHttpRequest will send the data along as `multipart/form-data`, which should make the individual fields accessible on $_POST. If you're using a library like axios to make the request, you may need to manually set the content-type header: `axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'your-url',
    data: formData,
    config: { headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }}
    })`
see: 
[using axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630163/axios-post-request-to-send-form-data)
[using json](https://dev.to/dev_nope/catch-and-parse-json-post-data-in-php-1p56)

Comment: if you're sending json-encoded data, then you will need to use `json_decode`. Check the 'using json' link in the previous comment for an example. Also see: [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813487/how-to-post-json-to-php-with-curl/813512), or use the method that Kaiido suggested.