# Why is php curl not working with application/json posting?

Tags: php, curl

I have a file on a remote server (www.oneofmysites.com/hitme.php) that has:

```
<?php

    $d = array(
      'test' => 1,
      'request' => $_REQUEST,
      'post'    => $_POST,
      'get'     => $_GET,
      'server'  => $_SERVER,
      'session' => $_SESSION,
    );

    print '<pre>';
    print_r($d);
```

In other words, it just prints out a bunch of variables. I use this to test a post I send there. Which I do as follows:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('!!THIS_IS_GREAT!!' => 'VERY VERY GREAT!!!')));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

print $server_output;
```

If I run the code like this, with the "application/json" line commented out, then it returns values:

```
Array
(
    [test] => 1
    [request] => Array
        (
            [!!THIS_IS_GREAT!!] => VERY VERY GREAT!!!
        )
    [post] => Array
        (
            [!!THIS_IS_GREAT!!] => VERY VERY GREAT!!!
        )

    [get] => Array
    (
    )
```

But the moment I add this line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
```

Then the post returns:

```
Array
(
    [test] => 1
    [request] => Array
        (
        )
    [post] => Array
        (
        )

    [get] => Array
    (
    )
```

What am I doing wrong that would cause these values to not go through? Must I somehow enable json posting specifically? (I doubt it, because I have tried this on 2 different servers).

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I figured it out myself that I had to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15643608/146366):

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")),1).'</pre>';
```

It doesn't make sense to me that this doesn't work:

```
$_POST
```

But this does:

```
file_get_contents("php://input")
```

If anyone knows why, please share.

Comment: my friend you most be parse array your warning is here
you can use foreach loop to parse array or echo $_POST ['test']
your print have array most be parse

Comment: PHP has been a while for me but why would you want to post form fields and declare your content as json? Because it isn't.

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('!!THIS_IS_GREAT!!' => 'VERY VERY GREAT!!!')));`

If you want it to be json just format it as json and put it in the body of your post.

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813487/how-to-post-json-to-php-with-curl/813510#813510  which says I believe you are getting an empty array because PHP is expecting the posted data to be in a Querystring format (key=value&key1=value1).

Comment: PHP only parses `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` post requests into `$_POST`, as this content type is commonly used for forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the [superglobals](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) are documented to parse JSON. Particularly, [$_POST](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) is described as:

> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method when using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` as the HTTP Content-Type in the request.

You can inspect raw POST data with the [php://input](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input) stream wrapper (e.g. using [file_get_contents()](https://php.net/file_get_contents)) and you can decode JSON with [json_decode()](https://php.net/json_decode).